# problemas a la hora de editar un consulta msql en un formulario

Tags: php, html, mysqli

**hola tengo una problemas a la hora de hacer una consulta mysql **
 voy a pasar los siquiente codigos:

1 parte   donde  " class="btn btn-danger  fas fa-edit fa-lg m-1 "> va ha imprimir todo el el formulario y va a llevar un fichero edit.php

```html
       <tbody>

            <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM listado";
            $resultadolista = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultadolista)) {

                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['serie'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['unidad_principal'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['unidad1'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['unidad2'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['unidad3'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['unidad4'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['fecha_cadu'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['fecha_echa'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ciudad'];?></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="btn btn-danger  fas fa-edit fa-lg m-1 "></a>
                            <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="btn btn-primary fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg  m-1 "></a>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>


            <?php  } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

2 parte
el fichero de edit.php

```html
<?php
include('db.php');
$serie = '';
$unidad_principal = '';
$unidad1 = '';
$unidad2 = '';
$unidad3 = '';
$unidad4 = '';
$fecha_cadu = '';
$fecha_echa = '';
$ciudad = '';

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM listado WHERE id = $id ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $serie = $row['serie'];
        $unidad_principal = $row['unidad_principal'];
        $unidad1 = $row['unidad1'];
        $unidad2 = $row['unidad2'];
        $unidad3 = $row['unidad3'];
        $unidad4 = $row['unidad4'];
        $fecha_cadu = $row['fecha_cadu'];
        $fecha_echa = $row['fecha_echa'];
        $ciudad = $row['ciudad'];
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $serie = $_POST['serie'];
    $unidad_principal = $_POST['unidad_principal'];
    $unidad1 = $_POST['unidad1'];
    $unidad2 = $_POST['unidad2'];
    $unidad3 = $_POST['unidad3'];
    $unidad4 = $_POST['unidad4'];
    $fecha_cadu = $_POST['fecha_cadu'];
    $fecha_echa = $_POST['fecha_echa'];
    $ciudad = $_POST['ciudad'];

    $query = "UPDATE listado SET serie = '$serie' , unidad_principal='$unidad_principal', unidad1='$unidad1', unidad2='$unidad2', unidad3='$unidad3', unidad4='$unidad4',fecha_cadu='$fecha_cadu',fecha_echa='$fecha_echa', ciudad='$ciudad' WHERE id = $id";
    header('Location:index.php');
}

?>
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>

<div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class=" m-1 text-center">Editar</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 p-5">
        <form action="edit.php? id = <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="POST">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">SERIE</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="serie" name="serie" value="<?php echo $serie; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <label>Unidad 1</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Unidad 1" name="unidad_principal" value="<?php echo $unidad_principal; ?>">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <label>Unidad 2</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Unidad 2" name="unidad1" value="<?php echo $unidad1; ?>">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <label for="validationTooltip01">Unidad 3</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Unidad 3" name="unidad2" value="<?php echo $unidad2; ?>">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <label for="validationTooltip01">Unidad 4</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Unidad 4" name="unidad3" value="<?php echo $unidad3; ?>">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                    <label for="validationTooltip01">Unidad 5</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Unidad 5" name="unidad4" value="<?php echo $unidad4; ?>">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">fecha caducada</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="fecha caducada" name="fecha_cadu" value="<?php echo $fecha_cadu; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">fecha hecha </label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="fecha hecha" name="fecha_echa" value="<?php echo $fecha_echa; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">ciudad </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ciudad" name="ciudad" value="<?php echo $ciudad; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill" name="update">Actualizar </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>




<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

con su correspodiente consulta UPDATE  para cuando le doy clip  al [Actualizar ] lo manda actualizado . 
he probrado con un input de tipo submit pero tampoco funciona . 
me podria ayudar, ademas me parece raro poque no me da problemas de en el navegador he mirado tambien  el puerto de mysql el host y el root pero esta correctamento ya que mandar consulta en la tabla me lo hace pero actualizar no me deja .
GRACIAS ANTE MANO VUESTRA AYUDA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hace falta ejecutar la sentencia SQL para realizar el `update`, la puede realizar agregando `mysqli_query($conn, $query)` antes de la sentencia del `header`.

Comment: Ya lo he puesto la sentencia pero aún. No me deja actualizar.  No lo manda al servidor

Comment: Otra cosa puede ser que me falle porque he añadido la librería html2pdf en la carpeta y de fallo por eso